# how to access custom control value in lightswitch

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

i have create following custom control for lightswitch and how can i access and get data?

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomControls.DateRange"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="75" d:DesignWidth="123">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="73">
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,9,0,0" Name="cmbStartYear" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,39,0,0" Name="cmbStartMonth" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

xaml.vb file coding :
in here i added values for those combo boxes based on my logic.

```
Private Sub UserControl_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Dim availableYears As List(Of Integer) = GetYears()

        For Each year As Integer In availableYears
            cmbStartYear.Items.Add(year)
        Next
    End Sub
```

then i add that custom control to screen. (first create property and then assign custom control to that)

[image]

when it runs it will display as below
[image]

so my question is how can i access these two combo boxes  and get its value?

i found that

```
Dim cmbyear As IContentItemProxy = Me.FindControl("StartYear")
```

can be used to access control. but how i can i get value of each control separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done as follows : first have to create local properties and in custom control need to bind them with those values.

in my scenario i have created two local properties called  StartYear/StartMonth . then in custom control need to bind them to `SelectedItem` and mode must be `TwoWay` . i did it as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="73">
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,9,0,0" Name="cmbStartYear" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" SelectedItem="{Binding Screen.StartYear, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,39,0,0" Name="cmbStartMonth" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" SelectedItem="{Binding Screen.StartMonth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
```

then within my xaml.vb code can directly access those local properties.